# Multi-threaded code crashes on server but not on VS

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a multi-threaded c# code that connects to a MySql server.

```
List<string> itemLst=new List<string>();
//fills the list here
ParallelOptions po=new ParallelOptions();
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 45;
Parallel.ForEach(itemLst,po,item=>
{
//Open connection to MySql server
//do some SELECT queries
//do 1 insert and 1 delete query
//close and dispose connection
}
```

when I run this code in visual studio (2017) in Debug (with IIS Express) everything works fine but when I upload the code to a linux server (ubuntu 16.04) it crashes.
I've tried running it with dotnet run to see the exception and I recieved the following:

> AggregateException: One or more errors occured (Connect Timeout
>   expired.) --->  System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a
>   disposed object.

MySql server specs:
128GB RAM, 20 VCPUS (i7 cpus)
Ubuntu server spec:
64GB RAM, 16 VCPUS (i7 cpus)
Personal computer:
16GB RAM, 1 CPU (i7)

How would I go about solving this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you doing with `itemLst` in `Parallel.ForEach`? It is not thread safe. Can you post the complete code inside the ForEach block?

Comment: Sounds like you are running out of available connections. Have a look into the DB logs. Are there a lot of dangling connections? Maybe even reconsider using mutlithreading here in the first place. Did you verify it actually speeds up things? (i.e. do a benchmark)

Comment: I've used Peter Bons answer which helped a lot, yet another error returns once going up on the server with the syntax of "Attempted to read past end of stream". Every single non-concurrent object was change to a concurrent one (either a bag or a dict) and yet the app keeps crashing.

Comment: Have you considered posting the complete error log - to eliminate the mystery of what MySQL is trying to share with you?